# How come finding an $n/2$ size clique in a directed/ non directed graph is not in $\sf NL$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

obviously the "Finding an $n/2$ size clique in a directed/ non directed graph" is not $\sf NL$ but I'd really like to understand where does it fall in terms of the definition of the $\sf NL$ definition.

I have to have an input and witness tapes, both of them can be polynomial and a logarithmic size of work stripe. So why can't I just guess an $n/2$ clique, each time put 2 vertices on the work tape, check that they share an edge, and count them. The witness tape provides me each time two vertices from left to write, in total $O({\frac{n}{2}}^2)$. In order to count that I need $O(\log ({\frac{n}{2}}^2))$ which is logarithmic. so what's lacking or wrong with this attempt?

Comment: I'm getting a witness which suppose to be a clique, set of vertices. I go from the first one to all the rest, then from the second one to all the rest. Perhaps I can't go back to second?

Comment: I use the definition such that the witness does not have to be logarithmic space, The machine has 3 tapes: input, witness(Can be polynomial), only the space of the work tape counts. but important detail is that we can move only right way on the witness tape.

Comment: It doesn't need to be deterministically. I wabt to check them in linear space.

Answer (score 2):

(Turning my comments into an answer.)

You have to deterministically verify that the $\mathcal{O}(n)$ vertices on your *witness tape* form a clique.  Since you can only move to the right, you can only do linear amount of work for this set, however there are $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ *pairs of vertices* in the clique, and you have to check every pair.  Hence you cannot check every pair and thus not verify if it is a clique or not.

Note that this is not a proof that $\mathbf{Clique}$ is not in $\mathsf{NL}$, only that this algorithm (or idea) doesn't work.

Comment: Ok Thank you. so why Can't I put the witness $k$ times in a row, and check it that why? where doesn't it meet the conditions?

Comment: There is no $k$ in your original question, so do you mean any constant $c \in \mathbb{N}$, or $k=n$ or $k=n/2$?  In any case, the unsatisfactory answer to your question now would be because that's not the definition of $\mathsf{NL}$.  But to be able to fully appreciate why, you need to go into the details of the proof of why *your* definition (with witness) is equivalent to the *original* definition of $\mathsf{NL}$ (which is without witness).

Comment: The *original* definition of $\mathsf{NL}$ involves only a non-deterministic Turing machine with a log space working tape and a read-only input tape.  It does not involve your definition of a right-move-only witness tape, however you can show those definitions to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the wrong thing in your solution is that the definition you are using does not give an $\mathsf{NL}$ algorithm, it gives an $\mathsf{NP}$ algorithm.

Here is another way to explain the problem: in $\mathsf{NL}$ you can't really assume that you get a witness to verify which is of polynomial size (as we do in $\mathsf{NP}$). In fact if we take the polynomial size witness plus a log-space verifier we end up with $\mathsf{NP}$ not $\mathsf{NL}$ (and this is true even if we use weaker verifiers, as long as the witness is polynomial size and the class that verifier belongs to is capable of checking if a given string is an accepting computation of a given TM we end up with $\mathsf{NP}$).

So don't let the witness definition confuse you about $\mathsf{NL}$. An $\mathsf{NL}$ machine is *a nondeterministic machine which makes nondeterministic decisions and uses only logarithmic space* and we don't have a result that allows us to use a witness definition similar to the $\mathsf{NP}$ witness-verifier definition by just changing the verifier to be a log-space machine in place of a poly-time machine.

One can use a real-only read-once tape for a witness definition but that is not usually a good way of thinking about $\mathsf{NL}$. 
The witness verifier definition for $\mathsf{NP}$ is used because we end up with a very nice intuitive definition for $\mathsf{NP}$: verifying answers in polynomial time. We don't end up with a similarly nice definition for $\mathsf{NL}$.

ps: for completeness, it is consistent with the current state of knowledge that there is an $\mathsf{NL}$ algorithm for the problem. However, such an algorithm would imply $\mathsf{NL}=\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ since the problem is complete for $\mathsf{NP}$. Therefore although it is not completely ruled out, it is considered a very unlikely possibility (and you would win a 1 million dollar prize if you had such an algorithm).